# Can I call single page application an web 3.0 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, singlepage

Time is passing and we started to have more and more single page applications or frameworks like [new twitter](http://twitter.com/newtwitter) and [Sammy](http://code.quirkey.com/sammy/).

It seams like it is the next big step, where we eliminate generating code on server side, servers start to be only data providers, all the UI is done on single page using javascript.

I kn ow there is no real definition of Web 2.0 (except using ajax), so I do not except any definition of Web 3.0, I only search for indicators of our evolution of the next big step in application development.

So question is: Is single page application an web 3.0 start?

Note: I know there were questions about web 3.0, but they are old (almost one year for newest).

Comment: From what I can tell, you're free to call your site absolutely anything you want.  Personally I'm gravitating towards Web 3.14159.

Comment: @Pointy, but I'm afraid of what will happen when we upgrade to 3.14160

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web 3.0 is supposed to be the **semantic web**, where computers and robots understand your page.

Offcourse anyone is free to try and start their own definition. Some people believe Web 3.0 will be about **the Cloud**.

The difference between Web 1.0 (static authormade content) and Web 2.0 (visitors supply the content) is pretty huge, as is going to the Semantic Web or even the Cloud. I doubt a "one page site" is the same magnitude of change. Those existed in the 90's, but you probably use javascript - they used frames.

Comment: so single page applications using apis is a step also toward semantic web as it seams to be an requirement for making understanding data  easier for machines.

Comment: If you follow all the best practices, you could argue that. However, most AJAX-whipped-together pages are even less machine accessible than the simple HTML from 15 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

There IS a real, single definition of Web 2.0 from O'Reilly. Look it up. But all this concern about whether something is 2.0, 3.0, is pure silliness, snake oil and hogwash.